# Building option list with haml

Tags: sinatra, haml, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to create a select control with options using HAML in Sinatra. There should be an option for each value in my @ages array. I have verified that @ages is actually in the view by printing it out. My select tag however does not show these @ages.

```
%form
  %label='Portfolio Type'
  %select{name: :portfolio_type}
    %option{value: :cash}='Cash'
    %option{value: :securities}='Securities'
  %br
  %label='Current Age'
  %select{name: :current_age }
  - @ages.each do |age|
    %option{:name => age, :value=> age}="#{age}"
  %br
  %label='Current Savings'
  %input

  %input

  %input
```

below is the html that is being generated. I can see that the select tag is closing before the options.

```
<form>
        <label>Portfolio Type</label>
        <select name='portfolio_type'>
          <option value='cash'>Cash</option>
          <option value='future_advisor'>Future Advisor</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label>Current Age</label>
        <select name='current_age'></select>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='26'>26</option>
        <option value='27'>27</option>
        <option value='28'>28</option>
        <option value='29'>29</option>
        <option value='30'>30</option>
        <option value='31'>31</option>
        <option value='32'>32</option>
        <option value='33'>33</option>
        <option value='34'>34</option>
        <option value='35'>35</option>
        <option value='36'>36</option>
        <option value='37'>37</option>
        <option value='38'>38</option>
        <option value='39'>39</option>
        <option value='40'>40</option>
        <option value='41'>41</option>
        <option value='42'>42</option>
        <option value='43'>43</option>
        <option value='44'>44</option>
        <option value='45'>45</option>
        <option value='46'>46</option>
        <option value='47'>47</option>
        <option value='48'>48</option>
        <option value='49'>49</option>
        <option value='50'>50</option>
        <br>
        <label>Current Savings</label>
        <input>
        <input>
        <input>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you paste the generated html?

Comment: @mus Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question. You can see that the select tag is being closed before the options. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed the select tag is closed before the options are listed.
That's Because you didn't indent the `- @ages.each do |age|` statement.

Change this:

```
%select{name: :current_age }
- @ages.each do |age|
  %option{:name => age, :value=> age}="#{age}"
```

To this:

```
%select{name: :current_age }
  - @ages.each do |age|
    %option{:name => age, :value=> age}="#{age}"
```